# need help for my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help for my query:

```
SELECT 
P.ID,
P.CategoryID,
P.Name,
P.SupplierID,
p.UnitPrice,
p.UnitsInStock,
pp.PicturePath
FROM Products P JOIN ProductPhoto PP ON p.ID=PP.ProductID   WHERE P.CategoryID='2';
```

This query gives me 2 results but it must give me 4 result because there are 4 data whose `categoryID='2'`

Also I have checked from this query and there are 4 data whose `categoryID='2'`

```
 select * from Products;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  P.ID,
  P.CategoryID,
  P.Name,
  P.SupplierID,
  p.UnitPrice,
  p.UnitsInStock,
  pp.PicturePath
FROM Products P 
LEFT JOIN ProductPhoto PP 
  ON p.ID=PP.ProductID  
WHERE P.CategoryID='2'
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all `Products` even if there is no matching row in the `ProductPhoto` table.  The `INNER JOIN` will only return rows that match in both tables.

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax then here is a great [visual explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
P.ID,
P.CategoryID,
P.Name,
P.SupplierID,
p.UnitPrice,
p.UnitsInStock,
pp.PicturePath
FROM Products P LEFT JOIN ProductPhoto PP ON p.ID=PP.ProductID   WHERE P.CategoryID='2'
```

Try use left join, it is possible that there is no productionPhoto records matching product.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are doing an INNER JOIN onto ProductPhoto on the ProductID which equals the ID within Products.

If there are only 2 matching rows in both tables with a categoryID of 2, then that's all you will see returned.

Change your query to be a LEFT JOIN and see if your 4 rows returned. If they are, then your above query is correct.